# Slideshow using migx TV on different resources ans templates

Tags: modx

I made a slideshow using Mootools SmoothGallery on my MODx revolution website, and I use Migx to select the images dynamically. 
It works well on my first page, but I'd like to use the same slideshow on other pages of the site (this slideshow is in the header of the site). 
I tried to assign the main Migx TV to a different template, but the slideshow doesn't show up on the resource using this template, it only works on the 1st one.

Is it impossible to use the same Migx on different places of a site ?

Call of the chunk containing the slideshow on my 2 templates :

```
<div id="slideshowbox">[[$slideshowbox]]</div><!--end slideshowbox-->
```

Content of the chunk "slideshowbox"

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function startGallery() {
    var myGallery = new gallery($('myGallery'), {
    timed: true,
    showArrows: false,
    showCarousel: false,
    embedLinks: false
    });
    }
    window.addEvent('domready', startGallery);
    </script> 

<div id="myGallery">
[[!getImageList?
      &tvname=`SlideShow`
      &tpl=`SlideImage`
   ]]
</div>
```

Content of SlideImage

```
<div class="imageElement">
<h3>[[+title]]</h3>
<p>[[+description]]</p>
<img src="[[+image]]" class="full" />
</div>
```

Migx TV : SlideShow
Tabs :

```
[
{"caption":"Image", "fields":[
    {"field":"image","caption":"Image size 938px x 344px","inputTV":"image"}
]},
{"caption":"Info", "fields": [
    {"field":"title","caption":"Title"},
    {"field":"description","caption":"Description"}
]}
```

Grids :

```
[
{"header": "Title", "width": "160", "sortable": "true", "dataIndex": "title"},
{"header": "Image", "width": "50", "sortable": "false", "dataIndex": "image","renderer": "this.renderImage"}
]
```

And in the head section of my 2 templates :

```
<!--JQuery-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--SmoothGallery-->
<script src="assets/js/mootools-1.2.1-core-yc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/mootools-1.2-more.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jd.gallery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jd.gallery.transitions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The result on the resource of the 1st template :

```
<div id="slideshowbox"><script type="text/javascript">
function startGallery() {
var myGallery = new gallery($('myGallery'), {
timed: true,
showArrows: false,
showCarousel: false,
embedLinks: false
});
}
window.addEvent('domready', startGallery);
</script> 
<div id="myGallery">
<div class="imageElement">
<h3>Sanctuaire d'Itsukushima</h3>
<p>Corridor (Kairo)</p>
<img src="assets/images/img_temp/slideshow/kairo.jpg" class="full" />
</div><div class="imageElement">
<h3>Mikasahama</h3>
<p>Lanternes et Torii flottant</p>
<img src="assets/images/img_temp/slideshow/lanternes.jpg" class="full" />

</div><div class="imageElement">
<h3>Illuminations Nocturnes</h3>
<p>Sanctuaire d'Itsukushima et Pagode à 5 étages (Goju-no-to)</p>
<img src="assets/images/img_temp/slideshow/lightup.jpg" class="full" />
</div><div class="imageElement">
<h3>Sommet du Mont Misen</h3>
<p>et vue sur les îles de la Mer Intérieure de Seto</p>
<img src="assets/images/img_temp/slideshow/misen.jpg" class="full" />
</div><div class="imageElement">
<h3>Tour Tahoto</h3>
<p>au milieu des cerisiers en fleur</p>

<img src="assets/images/img_temp/slideshow/tahoto.jpg" class="full" />
</div><div class="imageElement">
<h3>Tsutusmigaura</h3>
<p>Plage et parc sportif</p>
<img src="assets/images/img_temp/slideshow/sea.jpg" class="full" />
</div>
</div></div><!--end slideshowbox-->
```

Result on the second one :

```
<div id="slideshowbox"><script type="text/javascript">
function startGallery() {
var myGallery = new gallery($('myGallery'), {
timed: true,
showArrows: false,
showCarousel: false,
embedLinks: false
});
}
window.addEvent('domready', startGallery);
</script> 
<div id="myGallery">

</div></div><!--end slideshowbox-->
```

It's empty...

What should I do ?

---

EDIT :

Ok, I understood, why it was empty : because I have to fill again the form to input image and text for this resource, and it works..

So now what I'd like to know is how to get the variables from the first form I filled in order to show the same Slideshow on every pages of my site ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the getImageList snippet is referring to the SlideShow TV for the **current** page by default, which of course is empty for all except the first page.

You can specify the id of the first page which you have already loaded you images into using the **docid** parameter:

```
[[!getImageList?
      &tvname=`SlideShow`
      &tpl=`SlideImage`
      &docid=`1`    <-- id of document containing your images
   ]]
```

More info here: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/MIGX.Frontend-Usage#MIGX.Frontend-Usage-getImageList

Comment: You're welcome :) Would you mark my answer as 'correct' please? Cheers